# Grep a range of values with specific starting characters

Tags: awk, grep

I have 10GB files in which i want to count the occurrences of some specific text i.e TY[0-9].

Example file:

```
ABC,2A,2018-07-06,2018-06-20 00:00:00
BCD,TY1,2018-07-06,2018-06-20 00:00:00
EFG,TY2,2018-07-06,2018-06-20 00:00:00
IGH,2A,2018-07-06,2018-06-20 00:00:00
```

I want to get the count of all text starting with `TY` and then a digit. I tried using egrep but am not getting the correct result.

```
egrep  "^TY[0-9]" Filename
```

Comment: `^` means *beginning of a line*. You `TY` entries are not at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with your attempted solution is that it assumes that the sting `TY` occurs at the start of the line (you are anchoring the expression there with `^`), but it doesn't. It occurs at the start of the second comma-delimited field.

---

Using `awk` to count the number of times the second comma-delimited field in the file starts with the string `TY` followed by a digit:

```
awk -F, '$2 ~ /^TY[[:digit:]]/ { n++ } END { print n }' filename
```

I'm wondering whether using `cut` in combination with `grep` would be quick? Cutting out the second column would give `grep` less data to work with, and so it may be quicker than just `grep` alone.

```
cut -d, -f2 filename | grep -c '^TY[[:digit:]]'
```

... but I'm not sure.

---

After some testing on my OpenBSD system, using a 1.1GB file, the `cut`+`grep` is actually almost 50% quicker than `awk` (8 seconds vs. 15 seconds). And a pure `grep` solution (`grep -Ec '\<TY[0-9]' filename`, taken from [glenn's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451171/116858)) takes 13 seconds.

So if the string is to picked out of the second field only, one may gain some time by extracting only that field before matching.

Comment: In your second example, why not `cut -d, -f2 inputfile | grep -c [...]` rather than `| grep | wc -l`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Derrp. Yes. Thanks. Made it even quicker too.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a word boundary instead of the start-of-line anchor:

```
$ grep -Ec '\<TY[0-9]' file
2
```

Note: that is a count of all **lines** with a "TY word". It is not a count of all "TY word"s. If you can have more than one per line, then

```
$ grep -Eo '\<TY[0-9]' file | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the number of occurrence of a `,` delimited field that starts with `TY` and is followed by any number of decimal digits, you could do:

```
<file perl -lne '$n += () = /(?<![^,])TY\d+(?![^,])/g; END{print 0+$n}'
```

Which on an input like:

```
TY1,TY2,TY,TYFOO
TY213,X-TY2,TY4
```

Would return `4` (`TY1`, `TY2`, `TY213`, `TY4`).

`(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are respectively negative look behing and ahead operators. So here, we're looking for `TY` followed by one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`), provided its neither preceded nor followed by a character other than `,`.

Another way to do it would be to convert `,`s to newlines and count the number of resulting lines that start with `TY` followed by one or more digits:

```
<file tr , '\n' | LC_ALL=C grep -xEc 'TY[[:digit:]]+'
```

(on my system, that's about 10 times as fast as the `perl` solution)